# In the forge viewer I can add a new THREE.Object3D, but I can't select it in the viewer.

Tags: autodesk-forge

In the Forge Viewer I have written a custom handler. It has a bound double-click event that when it fires with the event, calculates the item being clicked on with

```
const hitTest = this.viewer.clientToWorld(event.canvasX, event.canvasY, true);
```

For a normal object/mesh/material, that works OK, and hitTest.dbId is returned, plus a hitTest.point object indicates where in 3D space I clicked. I use that location to create a material, mesh and object, then add to the scene. (A few small steps skipped)

```
var material_orange = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFEBD17});
this.viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial('SBD-Material-' + 'orange', material_orange, true);
var sphereMesh =
         new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.SphereGeometry(niceRadius, 20),
                material_orange);
var sphereModel = new THREE.Object3D();
sphereModel.add(sphereMesh);
sphereModel.position.set(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, atPoint.z);

this.viewer.impl.scene.add(sphereModel);
this.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);
```

All that works great. The sphere is added to my model. (It's black, I still can't figure out why...) But the biggest problem is that I can't click on the sphere. Clicking on it selects the underlying object in the model, usually a wall or floor.

Do I need to use a RayTrace method to get the objects in the scene? Or is there a property to the object/mesh/material that will make it clickable? A viewer update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this moment, you must have to create an owned tool that inherits the `Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface` and put your clicking logic in the `handleSingleClick` function. Here is a example for this case:

1. The custom tool:

   ```
   class CustomTool extends Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface {
       constructor( viewer ) {
           super();
           this._viewer = viewer;
           this._active = false;
           this._names = [ 'CustomTool' ];
       }

       get viewer() {
           return this._viewer;
       }

       isActive() {
           return this._active;
       }

       handleSingleClick( event, button ) {
           const _viewer = this.viewer;
           const intersectObjects = (function () {
               const pointerVector = new THREE.Vector3();
               const pointerDir = new THREE.Vector3();
               const ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
               const camera = _viewer.impl.camera;

               return function(pointer, objects, recursive) {
                   const rect = _viewer.impl.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                   const x = (( pointer.clientX - rect.left) / rect.width ) * 2 - 1;
                   const y = - (( pointer.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height ) * 2 + 1;

                   if (camera.isPerspective) {
                       pointerVector.set( x, y, 0.5 );
                       pointerVector.unproject( camera );
                       ray.set( camera.position, pointerVector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
                   } else {
                       pointerVector.set( x, y, -1 );
                       pointerVector.unproject( camera );
                       pointerDir.set( 0, 0, -1 );
                       ray.set( pointerVector, pointerDir.transformDirection( camera.matrixWorld ) );
                   }

                   const intersections = ray.intersectObjects( objects, recursive );
                   return intersections[0] ? intersections[0] : null;
               };
           })();

           const pointer = event.pointers ? event.pointers[ 0 ] : event;
           // Intersect objects in the scene
           const result = intersectObjects( pointer, _viewer.impl.scene.children );

           if( result && result.object ) {
               const mesh = result.object;
               // Change object color
               let curColor = mesh.material.color;
               curColor = ( curColor.getHex() == 0xff0000 ? 0x00ff00 : 0xff0000 );
               mesh.material.color.setHex( curColor );

               // Refreah viewport
               this.viewer.impl.invalidate( false, true, true );
           }

           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. The viewer extension managed this custom tool:

   ```
   class CustomToolExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
       constructor( viewer, options ) {
           super( viewer, options );
           this._tool = undefined;
       }

       load() {
           // Construct an custom Tool instance
           this._tool = new CustomTool( this.viewer );
           // Register custom Tool into viewer.toolController
           this.viewer.toolController.registerTool( this._tool );
           // Activate the Tool
           this.viewer.toolController.activateTool( 'CustomTool' );

           return true;
       }

       unload() {
           // If tool has been activated, deactivate the tool.
           if( this._tool.isActive() ) {
               this.viewer.toolController.deactivateTool( 'CustomTool' );
           }
          // Deregister custom Tool 
           this.viewer.toolController.deregisterTool( this._tool );

           return true;
       }
   }

   Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension( 'Autodesk.ADN.Sample.CustomToolExtension', CustomToolExtension );
   ```

Hope this help.

Comment: Can you tell, how class CustomTool is extending Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface as its an interface ?

Comment: In JavaScript, there is no interface, `Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface` is a predefined object ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)) as the base class for viewer tool. you can directly create something like `CustomTool ` and don't extend `Autodesk.Viewing.ToolInterface`